# How to create a printable 2-page CV in Photoshop

Tags: print-design

I typed my cv in a word processor. It is 2 pages long. I have also created a photoshop design using the A4 dimensions.

I have noticed that not only do I need two pages but also it would help the design in the canvas was slightly bigger.

Can you recommend me what canvas sizes are most appropriate for a photoshoped cv, and also how would I go about exporting two pages into pdf - do I create two photoshop files and somehow join them as one pdf?

Comment: I think you'd be far better served by designing your CV in the word processor, InDesign, Illustrator, or pretty much anything that's not Photoshop. :D It's not really intended for this task.

Comment: @MarcEdwards thanks for the suggestion, I figured out how to add 2 pages in illustrator. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarcEdwards Could you post this as an answer? It looks like it was useful to the OP, and we would avoid ending up with an unanswered question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'd be far better served by designing your CV in the word processor, InDesign, Illustrator, or pretty much anything that's not Photoshop. It's not really intended for this task.

Some suggestions, assuming the end result is going to be a PDF:

- Adobe InDesign.
- Adobe Illustrator.
- Apple Pages.
- Apple TextEdit (yep, it's actually really powerful and already on your Mac!).
- Microsoft Word.
- Many other page layout or word processing apps.

If you have several pages that you want to join to form a single PDF, Apple's free Automator can do it (already in your Applications folder). If you're using Windows, I bet there's easy ways to do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrators, please learn why a page layout program is beneficial.

For example, InDesign. If you make (for example) a box layout in Illustrator with the the same product logos in multiple locations, each time you copy that logo it increases the file size, because you are copying vectors.

If you make the same box layout using InDesign, you will import the logo file to a frame. The frame is a place holder for the content. When you want multiples of the same logo, you can copy the frame. Since the frame only *references* the logo artwork, the frame is more efficient than the Illustrator method, since the amount of bytes for defining a four-point vector frame is **WAAAAAAY** less than the amount of bytes in an artwork file.

Also, since you didn't copy artwork with this method, any changes in the logo will follow through to each instance in the layout (Saving changes to the same filename as the original ensures that you don't have to re-link). A 544MB AI file can become as small as a 6MB INDD file by following this method. If you were sending this file, wouldn't you want the smaller one?

In conclusion, work smarter, not harder.